# Geometric interpretation of the OLS minimum

Tags: regression, optimization, least-squares

I was reading [this question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30456/geometric-interpretation-of-penalized-linear-regression) to understand the geomteric interpretation of OLS solution. I have seen this before, and I understand it: given that I take for granted that the minima can be interpreted as contour plots.

My question is how exactly I can relate the contour plots to this question. Why do we draw different contours for the objective and the penalty? If I can understand that, I can easily make a leap to why the intersection reveals the minimum (but any help with that would be greatly appreaciated as well).

Comment: Are you asking about regular OLS or penalized regression models such as lasso and ridge regression?

Comment: Either or both. But I think I understood it now. The penalty term arises from a constraint term, so the contour is a constraint set. I just need to find a resource which shows how the constrained problem turns into this (unless you can point me to that?).